# Mplayer not working after upgrading to 14.04

Tags: 14.04, upgrade, video, mplayer, smplayer

Last night I upgraded to 14.04 from 13.10. After reboot, I can't play mp4 videos on smplayer. (and also from mplayer using terminal) I get following error.

```
$ mplayer '/home/vishwaje/Desktop/A-ha - Take On Me Official Music video - YouTube [360p].mp4'
Creating config file: /home/vishwaje/.mplayer/config
MPlayer 1.1-4.8 (C) 2000-2012 MPlayer Team
mplayer: could not connect to socket
mplayer: No such file or directory
Failed to open LIRC support. You will not be able to use your remote control.

Playing /home/vishwaje/Desktop/A-ha - Take On Me Official Music video - YouTube [360p].mp4.
libavformat version 54.20.4 (external)
Mismatching header version 54.20.3
libavformat file format detected.


MPlayer interrupted by signal 11 in module: demux_open
- MPlayer crashed by bad usage of CPU/FPU/RAM.
  Recompile MPlayer with --enable-debug and make a 'gdb' backtrace and
  disassembly. Details in DOCS/HTML/en/bugreports_what.html#bugreports_crash.
- MPlayer crashed. This shouldn't happen.
  It can be a bug in the MPlayer code _or_ in your drivers _or_ in your
  gcc version. If you think it's MPlayer's fault, please read
  DOCS/HTML/en/bugreports.html and follow the instructions there. We can't and
  won't help unless you provide this information when reporting a possible bug.
 [ This binary of MPlayer in Debian is currently compiled with
   '--enable-debug'; the debugging symbols are in the package
   'mplayer-dbg'.]
```

So I reinstalled, and did anything I can. But no luck. Please help.